# Get the state from a cell of csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, extract

I have a csv file which has address in a particular column. It is something like this:
[image]

I want to make a seperate column 'State' which has the state corresponding to each row and if it is not present, leave it empty.

I have done this till now:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

def loc(token):
   result = re.split('; |, |\*|\n', token)

   States = [ 'AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA',
           'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME',
           'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
           'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX',
           'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY', 'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas',
           'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho',
           'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland',
           'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska',
           'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 
           'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina',
           'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 
           'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']

   for state in States:
      for word in result:
         if state == word:
            return state
   return none

df['State'] = df['Info'].apply(lamda token: loc(token))
```

This does not give me the State for PQR and STU. I am not able to think of a logic, because I can't uppercase the entire input of the function. Please help if possible.

Comment: You don't have the same case, use `if state.casefold() == word.casefold()`. Note that you could also craft a special regex to extract the state directly.